# wordcloud2 shiny output creates extra widget

Tags: r, shiny, word-cloud

Using the rshiny example on the wordcloud2 cran page (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html), I get a small extra box beneath the wordcloud. This happens whenever I use the wordcloud2 package's rshiny functionality:

[image]

The code generating this is just:

```
library(wordcloud2)
# Global variables can go here
n <- 1

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('size', 'Size of wordcloud', n),
  wordcloud2Output('wordcloud2')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    # wordcloud2(demoFreqC, size=input$size)
    wordcloud2(demoFreq, size=input$size)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I am not sure if you noticed. There is a mouseover functionality, that enables you to see how many observations exists per word. Hover over a word and you will see a small box with the word and the amount of occurences. Moreover, you will notice that the small box you were talking about in the lower left hand corner will vanish. So the box is as long in the lower left hand corner until you hover over a word (and create a "new box"). Seems to be an odd default choice for that box, i agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of removing the box is to use CSS styling to set the element to not display. This can be done just by adding this code to the body of the UI:

```
tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML('div#wcLabel {display: none;}'))
    )
```

Note that this also kills the scroll-over functionality that shows the frequency of terms when you hover over a word. In my case, this was desirable.

Comment: what worked exactly for me was `tags$style(type='text/css', '.wcLabel {display:none;}'),`

Answer (score 2):

I solved by using this `wordcloud2a()` function instead of the regular `wordcloud2()`

```
wordcloud2a <- function (data, size = 1, minSize = 0, gridSize = 0, fontFamily = "Segoe UI", 
          fontWeight = "bold", color = "random-dark", backgroundColor = "white", 
          minRotation = -pi/4, maxRotation = pi/4, shuffle = TRUE, 
          rotateRatio = 0.4, shape = "circle", ellipticity = 0.65, 
          widgetsize = NULL, figPath = NULL, hoverFunction = NULL) 
{
  if ("table" %in% class(data)) {
    dataOut = data.frame(name = names(data), freq = as.vector(data))
  }
  else {
    data = as.data.frame(data)
    dataOut = data[, 1:2]
    names(dataOut) = c("name", "freq")
  }
  if (!is.null(figPath)) {
    if (!file.exists(figPath)) {
      stop("cannot find fig in the figPath")
    }
    spPath = strsplit(figPath, "\\.")[[1]]
    len = length(spPath)
    figClass = spPath[len]
    if (!figClass %in% c("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "bmp", "gif")) {
      stop("file should be a jpeg, jpg, png, bmp or gif file!")
    }
    base64 = base64enc::base64encode(figPath)
    base64 = paste0("data:image/", figClass, ";base64,", 
                    base64)
  }
  else {
    base64 = NULL
  }
  weightFactor = size * 180/max(dataOut$freq)
  settings <- list(word = dataOut$name, freq = dataOut$freq, 
                   fontFamily = fontFamily, fontWeight = fontWeight, color = color, 
                   minSize = minSize, weightFactor = weightFactor, backgroundColor = backgroundColor, 
                   gridSize = gridSize, minRotation = minRotation, maxRotation = maxRotation, 
                   shuffle = shuffle, rotateRatio = rotateRatio, shape = shape, 
                   ellipticity = ellipticity, figBase64 = base64, hover = htmlwidgets::JS(hoverFunction))
  chart = htmlwidgets::createWidget("wordcloud2", settings, 
                                    width = widgetsize[1], height = widgetsize[2], sizingPolicy = htmlwidgets::sizingPolicy(viewer.padding = 0, 
                                                                                                                            browser.padding = 0, browser.fill = TRUE))
  chart
}
```

See [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/281#issuecomment-615888981) for further explanation/discussion