# Wordcloud2 - change the cursor to pointer, when hover over words

Tags: r, pointers, shiny, hover, wordcloud2

I want to make a Shiny App with a Wordcloud. But I'm having problems on changing the outcome, when the mouse hovers over the Words.
What I want is, that the mouse of the user changes to a pointer, when it hovers over the words.

I tried to put it in some kind of css-class (without really knowing, what I have done), based on answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43718871/15347694) and [here](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js/issues/47)

```
#in the body ui
(tags$head(tags$style(HTML('div#wcLabel {cursor: pointer;}')))
```

but it didn't work.

Here is a reproducible example

```
library(shiny)
library(wordcloud2)
# Global variables can go here
n <- 1

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(tags$head(
  tags$style(HTML('div#wcLabel {cursor: pointer;}'))
),
  numericInput('size', 'Size of wordcloud', n),
  wordcloud2Output('wordcloud2')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    # wordcloud2(demoFreqC, size=input$size)
    wordcloud2(demoFreq, size=input$size)
  })
}
# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know that there is a call `hoverFunction =`  in the `wordcloud2()` function, and I guess, I would have to put something in there, to achieve my goal, but I don't know what.

Any help would be really appreciated. Many Thanks!

Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#wcLabel has `pointer-events: none;` set by default. You can override that by using the `!important` rule.

```
div#wcLabel {cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto !important;}
```

Comment: I had a follow-up question, which I posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67389969/wordcloud2-click-event-and-mouse-pointer