# Wordcloud2 - Click Event and Mouse pointer

Tags: r, shiny, hover, click, wordcloud2

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202256/wordcloud2-change-the-cursor-to-pointer-when-hover-over-words), rather it is possible to change the mouse to a pointer, when it hovers over the words in a wordcloud in shinyapp. The answer worked successfully.

```
library(shiny)
library(wordcloud2)
# Global variables can go here
n <- 1

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.wcLabel {cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto !important;}'))),
  numericInput('size', 'Size of wordcloud', n),
  wordcloud2Output('wordcloud2'),
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    # wordcloud2(demoFreqC, size=input$size)
    wordcloud2(demoFreq, size=input$size)
  })
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But now, `input$Wordcloud_clicked_word` won't react anymore.

(Edit: as HubertL correctly mentioned, using click event in the package of CRAN is not possible. However, installing the Version of GitHub makes it possible [as noted here](https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2).
So `devtools::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")` is needed to make click events possible)

```
library(shiny)
library(wordcloud2)
# Global variables can go here
n <- 1

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.wcLabel {cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto !important;}'))),
  numericInput('size', 'Size of wordcloud', n),
  wordcloud2Output('wordcloud2'),
  verbatimTextOutput("ClickedWord")
)

# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    # wordcloud2(demoFreqC, size=input$size)
    wordcloud2(demoFreq, size=input$size)
  })
  
  output$ClickedWord <- renderText(input$wordcloud2_clicked_word)
  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I change `.wcLabel`, then the verbatimTextOutput won't react anymore on clicking on a word in the cloud.

Is it possible to have both, the mouse changing to pointer on hover and reacting to clicking on a word?

Thanks!

Frederik

Comment: Is it possible to have the click event with workdcloud2 package from CRAN?

Comment: You are right, I edited the question. Thanks!